# How can I shift my Entry and Label widget to the right and align them in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am making a program on Tkinter,python and I want to move 3 label and entry widgets to the right so that they are in line and one below the other. I am using grid but its very frustrating because the column is not moving further than 6.
Here's the code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import Text
import tkinter as tk

win = tk.Tk()
win.geometry("1200x988")


def display_text():
    global entry
    string = entry.get()
    label.configure(text=string)

entry = Entry(win, width=40)
entry.focus_set()
label = Label(win, text="Name:", font=("Courier 22 bold"))
label.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W, pady=2)
entry.grid(row=1, column=0, pady=2)

label2 = Label(win, text="Number:", font=("Courier 22 bold"))
label2.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W, pady=2)
entry2 = Entry(win, width=40)
entry2.focus_set()
entry2.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=W, pady=2)

label3 = Label(win, text="Address:", font=("Courier 22 bold"))
label3.grid(row=4, column=0, sticky=W, pady=2)
entry3 = tk.Entry(win, width=60)
entry3.grid(row=5, column=0, sticky=W, ipady=20)

ttk.Button(win, text="Okay", width=20, 
command=display_text).grid(row=6, column=0, pady=2)

win.mainloop()
```

Comment: It is not clear what your problem is.  You put all widgets in column 0, so what do you mean by *"the column is not moving further than 6"*?

Answer (score 1):

Use rows *and* colums:

```
from tkinter import ttk
import os
import tkinter as tk

win = tk.Tk()
win.wm_title("Data entry")


def display_text():
    string = entry.get()
    if string:
        label.configure(text=string)


label = tk.Label(win, text="Name:", font=("Courier 22 bold"))
label.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.W, pady=2)
entry = tk.Entry(win, width=40)
entry.focus_set()
entry.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=tk.EW, pady=2)

label2 = tk.Label(win, text="Number:", font=("Courier 22 bold"))
label2.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=tk.W, pady=2)
entry2 = tk.Entry(win, width=40)
entry2.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=tk.EW, pady=2)

label3 = tk.Label(win, text="Address:", font=("Courier 22 bold"))
label3.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=tk.W, pady=2)
entry3 = tk.Entry(win, width=60)
entry3.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=tk.EW, ipady=20)

ttk.Button(win, text="Okay", command=display_text).grid(
    row=3, column=0, pady=2
)

win.mainloop()
```

The window will look like this:

[image: screenshot]]

I've left out the title bar on purpose; this looks different depending on the OS you use.Some additional points:

- Using `from tkinter import *` is considered bad style these days.
- Setting the geometry is not really necessary.
- Don't forget to set the window title with `wm_title`.
- Making the `Entry` widgets sticky on ease and west (`tk.EW`) makes them fill the column.
- Not prescribing the width of the button makes column 0 slimmer.
- Personally, I'd rather have all the text the same size, so I would set the font globally:

```
import tkinter.font as tkfont

win = tk.Tk()
win.wm_title("Data entry")

default_font = tkfont.nametofont("TkDefaultFont")
default_font.configure(
    family="Courier",
    size=22,
    weight="bold"
)
win.option_add("*Font", default_font)
```

(I've left out the title bar on purpose; this looks different depending on the OS you use.)

Comment: I actually wanted to align them in the extreme right side of my window. Could you help me with that?

Comment: @faryalrizvi See updated anser. I used `sticky=tk.EW` for the entry widgets.